# Compress multiple folders containing files into one zip using python

Tags: python, zip

I'm having a folder structure like this

```
Parent folder
   Folder1 
     1.txt
     2.msg
     ...
   Folder2
     1.txt
     2.py
     ...
```

My current approach is using shutil.make_archive I'm compressing the parent folder (eg: 13_03_2024.zip).
**Problem** is when extracting its showing
Parent folder >> folder1,folder2
**Expected** is only folder1, folder2

Could someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624800/shutil-make-archive-issue-dont-want-directories-included-in-zip-file

Comment: Hey Wera, checked that link. But still it is creating the parent folder inside the zip file. I just want to remove the parent folder from the zip file. It should directly extract the inner two folders.

Comment: Code added (answer below). Double click shows only two folders. In a couple of minutes I'll add unpack script

Answer (score 0):

I manually created 'test' directory in my Downloads folder and add your structure.

```
import shutil

shutil.make_archive(
    base_name =  '13_03_2024',
    format    =  'zip',
    root_dir  =  'test/', 
    base_dir  =  '.'
)
```

After running this code I extracted it successfully by selecting "Extract here..." - no parent folder

[image]

Also can be extracted by shutil:

```
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive(
    filename    = '13_03_2024.zip',
    extract_dir = '.',
    format      = 'zip')
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Wera,  This is my current code shutil.make_archive(final_input_dir, 'zip', final_input_path, 'Du-input') where final_input_dir=/opt/***/data/Ror-output/Du-input and final_input_path=/opt/***/data/Ror-output. "Du-input" is the parent directory which has two directories inside.

Comment: Well, does it work like you want?

Comment: No Could you please check my code and help me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile


def remove_parent_path(parent_path, file_path):
    # Get the relative path of the file_path with respect to the parent_path
    relative_path = os.path.relpath(file_path, parent_path)
    return relative_path


def compress_to(parent_path, out_file_path, structured_files=None, include_parent_dir=False):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(out_file_path, 'w') as zipf:
        for file in structured_files:
            if not include_parent_dir:
                zip_archive_name = remove_parent_path(parent_path, file)
            else:
                zip_archive_name = file
                zipf.write(file, zip_archive_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_dir = 'out'
    files_with_sub_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, '*', '*.*')
    out_file_path = 'sample.zip'`enter code here`
    files_list = glob.glob(files_with_sub_dir, recursive=True)
    compress_to(parent_dir, out_file_path, files_list, include_parent_dir=True)
```